# Bug(s) in the toolchain (compiler/debugger)?

Tags: c, debugging, gcc, gdb, x86-64

There is something terribly wrong with either gdb, gcc or both, and I don't know what. I've created a POC to reproduce it on `gcc (GCC) 4.6.1 20110819 (prerelease)` and `GNU gdb (GDB) 7.3.50.20110908-cvs` - yes, this is the CVS version, because I was running into this issue http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=12435, however I've also tested with `GNU gdb (GDB) 7.3.1` and it behaves the same.

Now to the POC: https://gist.github.com/1211017 the problem can be observed on line 33

In my opinion, `*c->foos[i]` should evaluate to the address of the i-th foo, as displayed by line 21. But the executable crashes, as you can see in the output.

Does anyone know what is wrong? An explanation at either the ASM level or GCC internals would be welcome.

**Addendum**:

1. The data structures are not allowed to change - they don't belong to my code, I have to interoperate with them.
2. The code `*c->foos[i]` used to work with older versions of gcc.
3. `dump_container` must have as parameter a `container*` - this function doesn't belong to my code either

Also worth mentioning: `*c->foos[i]` used to work.

Comment: -1: The existence of a POC and the existence of a platform configuration that allows this code to run seemingly correct does not imply a bug in the compiler toolchain. Always and never don't assume a compiler bug unless you have debugged your code and did some research on yourself. `Well, you have a POC, show me what I'm doing wrong.` is almost impolite in my opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running your code through the ever helpful valgrind says:

```
==16066== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==16066==    at 0x40061B: dump_container (bug.c:33)
==16066==    by 0x400726: main (bug.c:49)
==16066== 
==16066== Invalid read of size 4
==16066==    at 0x400620: dump_container (stdio2.h:105)
==16066==    by 0x400726: main (bug.c:49)
==16066==  Address 0x89485ed18949ed39 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==16066== 
==16066== 
==16066== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==16066==  General Protection Fault
==16066==    at 0x400620: dump_container (stdio2.h:105)
==16066==    by 0x400726: main (bug.c:49)
==16066==
```

My guess is that you'll find the bug in your own code rather than the compiler or debugger.

**EDIT** Or since you want me to spell it out for you, change line 33 to

```
printf("foo[%d]=%d at %p\n", i, (*c->foos)[i]->i, (void*) (*c->foos)[i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand how *c->foos[i] would have ever worked, `c->foos` gives a pointer to an array (a pointer to a bloc of pointers) (of pointers), according to line 43, when doing `c->foos[i]` you're not accessing to an element of the array. `(*c->foos)[i]` should work...

Take a look at the [C Operator Precedence Table](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm).

Comment: Then gcc says `error: request for member ‘i’ in something not a structure or union`

Comment: Forget about the value just yet. There is something wrong with the pointer, as you can see in the output. And it crashes, that pretty much speaks for itself (what it should do != what it does).

Answer (score 0):

> In my opinion, *c->foos[i] should evaluate to the address of the i-th
>   foo, as displayed by line 21.

No. If that is what you mean, you should use `&c->foos[i]`. Your version dereferences the i-th foo, what easily can lead to

> But the executable crashes, as you can see in the output.

.

Comment: On line 23 I want to see the same address as on lines 12 and 2. `&c->foos[i]` would show for instance `0x7fffb7c9abb8`

Comment: IMO redo the structure so it's harder to get confused by all the indirections and dereferences.

Comment: THe structure is not allowed to change, it belongs to a piece of code I must integrate my work in. That code is not mine.